# Bootstrap Modal inteiro e centralizado na página

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal

Coloquei Modal Bootstrap no meu template como teste para exibir mensagens na tela porém o mesmo aparece cortado no canto da tela. Como ajustar e centralizar o Modal na tela sem que fique cortado? Segue o código:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TELEFONE">
    <ItemTemplate>

        <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-    dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**Imagem**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Modais Bootstrap foram desenhados para sobrepor todo o conteúdo do documento `<body>` afim de poder rolar seu conteúdo.

Bootstrap não suporta o "aninhamento" de modais bem como sua documentação descreve que o usuário irá enfrentar problemas de renderização caso sejam utilizados dentro de um elemento com `position: fixed`... para todos os efeitos recomenda-se colocar seu HTML modal em uma posição de nível superior para evitar possíveis interferências de outros elementos.

Documentação:

- [Bootstrap 4 Beta 2](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/)
- [Bootstrap 3 (v3.3.7)](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals)
- [Botstrap 2 (v2.3.2)](https://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals)

O exemplo abaixo demonstra que tanto um modal em um nível superior quanto dentro de um contêiner ou coluna ocupam todo o espaço no documento `<body>`:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>




<section id="full-modal-example" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div  class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content rounded-0">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close cp" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <span class="icol">Hello World!</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>


<section class="container">
    <div class="col-5 offset-7">
        <section id="modal-in-column" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
            <div  class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content rounded-0">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title">Title</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close cp" data-dismiss="modal">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <span class="icol">Hello World2!</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</section>



<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#full-modal-example" class="btn btn-info">Full Modal</button>


<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-in-column" class="btn btn-info">Modal in Column</button>


<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Muito provavelmente você esteja lançando seu modal em um elemento com uma posição fixa ou alguma regra de seu **css** esteja impedindo que as definições de modal do Bootstrap sejam aplicadas.